# How to escape unicode special chars in string and write it to UTF encoded file

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf, unicode-escapes

What I aim to achieve is to:

string like:

```
Bitte überprüfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System eingereicht wurden, und löschen Sie dann die tatsächlichen Dokumente.
```

convert to:

```
'Bitte \u00FCberpr\u00FCfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System eingereicht wurden, und l\u00F6schen Sie dann die tats\u00E4chlichen Dokumente.'
```

and write it in this form to file (which is UTF-8 encoded).

Comment: Try `repr()` to convert it?

Comment: repr() produces the same string - did you something particular in mind ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution, not relying on the built-in `repr()` but rather implementing it from scratch:

```
orig = 'Bitte überprüfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System eingereicht wurden, und löschen Sie dann die tatsächlichen Dokumente.'

enc = re.sub('[^ -~]', lambda m: '\\u%04X' % ord(m[0]), orig)

print(enc)
```

Differences:

- Encodes only using `\u`, never any other sequence, whereas `repr()` uses about a third of the alphabet (so for example the BEL character will be encoded as `\u0007` rather than `\a`)
- Upper-case encoding, as specified (`\u00FC` rather than `\u00fc`)
- Does not handle unicode characters outside plane 0 (could be extended easily, given a spec for how those should be represented)
- It does not take care of any pre-existing `\u` sequences, whereas `repr()` turns those into `\\u`; could be extended, perhaps to encode `\` as `\u005C`:

  ```
  enc = re.sub(r'[^ -[\]-~]', lambda m: '\\u%04X' % ord(m[0]), orig)
  ```

Comment: This is very clean solution. Thank you :) Exactly what I needed. It actually converts some character that the "ascii" method did not, e.g. : „”

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be [ascii()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii):

```
string = 'Bitte überprüfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System ' \
         'eingereicht wurden, und löschen Sie dann die tatsächlichen Dokumente.'

print(ascii(string))
```

output :

```
'Bitte \xfcberpr\xfcfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System eingereicht wurden, und l\xf6schen Sie dann die tats\xe4chlichen Dokumente.'
```

Also you can use `unicode-escape` and `raw-unicode-escape` to achive this ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)) :

```
string = 'Bitte überprüfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System ' \
         'eingereicht wurden, und löschen Sie dann die tatsächlichen Dokumente.'

print(string.encode('unicode-escape').decode('raw-unicode-escape'))
```

output :

```
Bitte \xfcberpr\xfcfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System eingereicht wurden, und l\xf6schen Sie dann die tats\xe4chlichen Dokumente.
```

**Note** : `ascii()` will escape non-ascii characters with `\x` , `\u`, `\U` for 1 byte, 2 bytes and 4 bytes respectively. In your case you see `\x`. But try this one :

```
print(ascii('س'))  # '\u0633'
```

If you really want to convert `\xhh` escape sequences to `\u00hh` , use `re.sub()` on result of `ascii()`:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\\x[a-f0-9]{2}', lambda x: r'\u00' + x.group()[-2:].upper(), ascii(string)))
```

output :

```
'Bitte \u00FCberpr\u00FCfen Sie, ob die Dokumente erfolgreich in System eingereicht wurden, und l\u00F6schen Sie dann die tats\u00E4chlichen Dokumente.'
```

---

Above approaches works for escaping any non-ascii characters, if you intend to escape just those three Germany's alphabets and there is no other non-ascii characters, take a look at [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! While it works it produces "\x" character instead of "\u" characters, which will be the problem in the further process (the file will be proccessed by a different program/programming language). Any idea how to force "\u" character? E.g. 'ü' == '\u00FC' == '\xfc'

Comment: @PiWo honestly I don't know when `ascii()` generates \x and when \u.  In last case `print(ascii('س'))` we see \u. If you use those encodings I mentioned in the answer, you still having problem ? Doesn't it convert back to characters properly ?

Comment: The program that reads the final product has to have hard-coded conversion table for unicode character (it was written in Cobol, I have no sources) and it expects \u notation. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132950/1216005](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132950/1216005) explains more less that it's just shorter notation - I'll have to figure something out.

Comment: @PiWo I've added regex solution to convert those `\xhh`s to `\u00hh`. Now it's you expected result, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: I did something similiar with .replace('\x', '\u00'). It's not clean but it does the job for now as it is a unique problem for this particular situation. Thank you!

Comment: The only caveat with this would be if the string originally contains `\x` which would be encoded as `\\x` but should _not_ be converted to `\\u00`

Comment: Also, the question asked for upper-case, `\u00FC` rather than `\u00fc`; not sure if that matters

Comment: (Remember to also update the example output for the updated code.)

Comment: With the replacement getting more complex, it slowly converges with the approach of skipping `ascii()` and doing a `re.sub()` on the original string...

Comment: @sabik lol. or even better `str.translate()`, If he just needs this escaping for Germany's alphabets.